# How to get new image, changing the image name no effect, still reading the old image

Tags: iphone, ios

In my universal app I have some images in Resources folder by the convention "image.png" "image@2x.png"  etc.

When I **change names of the images** in the Resources folder I can see different images in the Simulator, But in real device whatever I do it keeps reading the previous image files. is there a cache mechanism or something do I need to clean or refresh about image files in Xcode3? Or I shouldn't change image names in res folder?

This is how I read:

```
+(UIImage *) APP_CRYSTAL_SELECTION{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cry" ofType:@"png"];
return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfResolutionIndependentFile:path]; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a Project > Clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, caching might be at play here. To repopulate any `imageView` I always pass my imageView through a setup method -

```
- (UIImageView *)setupImageView:(UIImageView *)imgView flags:(UIViewContentMode) mode
{
    [imgView setImage:nil];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1pixel.gif"]];
    if(mode)
        [imgView setContentMode:mode];
    else if(mode == 0)
        nil; //no flags
    return imgView;
}
```

Basically I reset the view with a simple 1pixel Image, now it's ready to be repopulated with any new image. hope this helps...

Comment: can you see my updated question how I get the image, how can I apply ur code there?

Comment: first off create an instance of `UIImageView` in your method. Then pass it reference to my above method. After that do what you must...

Comment: tnx, can I set nil instead of another image like 1pixel.gif

Comment: you can, but I wanted to be doubly sure.You can easily get a 1pixel image in google image search.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **[UIImage imageNamed:]**, it's loading the image from the cache and you should delete it! Read here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your app from simulator or clean all targets.